# What encoding scheme is used by Python 2.7 interpreter to encode Unicode code points before sending to terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am using python 2.7. My terminal's encoding scheme is set as 'utf-8'. Python's default encoding scheme is 'ascii'.

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

When I write

```
>>> print(u'à')
à
```

The correct Unicode character is displayed on my terminal. I am not getting what encoding scheme does python interpreter use to encode the Unicode code-point before sending it to the terminal. Is it UTF-8? But the default encoding scheme for python is set as 'ascii'. How does it decide to encode using UTF-8.

EDIT:
I know that I can specify the encoding myself as below:

```
>>> print(u'à'.encode('utf-8'))
à
```

But was wondering how does it work when I don't specify the encoding.

Comment: Check `sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: It says 'UTF-8'. Thanks.

Comment: Requested rollback of latest edit as the scope had been widened with additional question. Please ask additional question as a new question :)

Comment: Ok. Posted a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Python attempts to determine the terminal encoding and uses that encoding when printing to the terminal.  `sys.stdout.encoding` contains the encoding detected.  `getdefaultencoding()` is the encoding used to encode a Unicode string when no encoding is specified.

#### Example (Python 2 in Windows console):

```
>>> import sys
'ascii'
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp437'
```

Printing to terminal uses `sys.stdout.encoding`.  I use a Unicode character that is invalid in the terminal encoding to see the encoding in the error message:

```
>>> print u'\xc1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here I don't specify the encoding, and it uses the default:

```
>>> u'\xc1'.encode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

#### Example (Python 3 in Windows console):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp437'
```

Printing still uses `sys.stdout.encoding`:

```
>>> print('\xc1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python35\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xc1' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

But the encoding default is Python 3's default of `utf-8`:

```
>>> '\xc1'.encode()
b'\xc3\x81'
```

#### Redirecting Output

When redirecting output of a Python script, the value of `sys.stdout.encoding` can change.  This can be overridden with the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable.

Python 2 redirection doesn't detect the encoding.  It will default to `ascii`:

```
C:\>py -2 -c "import sys;print(sys.stdout.encoding)" | more
None
```

Python 3 uses the `ANSI` encoding (varies by Windows localization version):

```
C:\>py -3 -c "import sys;print(sys.stdout.encoding)" | more
cp1252
```

Overriding with the environment variable:

```
C:\>set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8

C:\>py -2 -c "import sys;print(sys.stdout.encoding)" | more
utf8

C:\>py -3 -c "import sys;print(sys.stdout.encoding)"
utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently, python picks up the encoding scheme for `sys.stdout` from the `LC_CTYPE` variable in your path.

```
ayush:~$ export LC_CTYPE=POSIX python
ayush:~$ python
Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```